# understand the meaning of DATEDIFF + LAG

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I need to understand what the meaning in this calculation :

```
DATEDIFF(days, lag(recday, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY  udid
                                           ORDER BY recday), recday)
```

And how can i implement it without using `lag` and `datediff`, for Amazon Redshift, which doesn't have `datediff` .

This is the full query :

```
SELECT udid
         ,recday AS day
         ,count(*) AS session_count
         ,DATEDIFF(days, lag(recday, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY  udid
                                           ORDER BY recday), recday) 
          AS repeat_transaction1
       ,DATEDIFF(days, lag(recday, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY  udid
                                           ORDER BY recday), recday) 
          AS repeat_transaction2
         ,DATEDIFF(days, lag(recday, 3) OVER (PARTITION BY  udid
                                           ORDER BY recday), recday) 
          AS repeat_transaction3
       ,DATEDIFF(days, lag(recday, 4) OVER (PARTITION BY  udid
                                           ORDER BY recday), recday) 
          AS repeat_transaction4
          ,DATEDIFF(days, lag(recday, 5) OVER (PARTITION BY  udid
                                           ORDER BY recday), recday) 
          AS repeat_transaction5
        ,DATEDIFF(days, lag(recday, 6) OVER (PARTITION BY  udid
                                           ORDER BY recday), recday) 
          AS repeat_transaction6
   FROM   vvdays
```

this is how my data looks -

10000001    2016-02-03 17:26:03.0
10000001    2016-02-08 21:36:07.0
10000001    2016-02-10 07:48:06.0
10000012    2016-02-06 22:06:42.0
10000012    2016-02-06 22:07:42.0
10000028    2016-02-04 13:18:48.0
10000028    2016-02-04 13:30:42.0
10000028    2016-02-04 13:30:55.0
10000028    2016-02-05 16:48:41.0
10000028    2016-02-05 16:58:34.0
10000028    2016-02-07 15:44:33.0
10000028    2016-02-07 16:29:00.0
10000039    2016-02-03 21:16:49.0
10000039    2016-02-03 21:17:50.0
10000039    2016-02-03 21:18:49.0
10000039    2016-02-03 21:19:49.0
10000039    2016-02-03 21:20:50.0
10000039    2016-02-03 21:21:50.0
10000039    2016-02-03 21:22:51.0
10000039    2016-02-03 21:23:53.0
10000039    2016-02-03 21:24:49.0
10000039    2016-02-03 21:25:50.0
10000039    2016-02-03 21:26:50.0
10000039    2016-02-03 21:27:49.0
10000039    2016-02-05 21:58:59.0
10000039    2016-02-05 21:59:58.0
10000039    2016-02-05 22:00:58.0
10000039    2016-02-05 22:01:58.0
10000039    2016-02-05 22:02:59.0
10000039    2016-02-05 22:03:58.0
10000039    2016-02-05 22:05:00.0
10000039    2016-02-05 22:05:58.0
10000039    2016-02-05 22:06:58.0

Comment: Oracle or sql-server?

Comment: its a redshift query , i need to implement it without lag and datediff

Comment: Assuming SQL-Server by your code, I removed the Oracle tag

Comment: I think you can factor the `lag` out, `datediff` will be a lot trickier.

Comment: how can i factor the lag out ? datediff maybe i can implement using datepart and dateadd

Comment: For `lag` you'll have to self-join with a `row_number()` (most likely) in order to determine the relevant previous row.

Comment: can you try to rewrite the query ?

Comment: Amazon Reshift supports both LAG and DATEDIFF.

Comment: the row number i should put partitioned by udid right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your data, I'm guessing that your table 'vvdays' contains the two fields 'udid' and 'recday'. The LAG function is getting the second, third, fourth, fifth, sixth and seventh rows of data based upon the udid. The DATEDIFF is then comparing the first 'recday' to the other lines and returning the number of days between these two dates.

How you replicate this in redshift is another issue, you could look at using UNPIVOT to get the top 7 results into the same row and then running your DATEDIFF equivalent functions on the fields themselves.

EDIT: Ok, I've designed a really hacky way of getting this working;

Create temp table for testing purposes;

```
CREATE TABLE #vvdays (udid int, recday datetime)
```

Inserting some data EDIT: now using OP's supplied data;

```
VALUES 
('10000001', '2016-02-03 17:26:03.0') 
,('10000001', '2016-02-08 21:36:07.0') 
,('10000001', '2016-02-10 07:48:06.0') 
,('10000012', '2016-02-06 22:06:42.0') 
,('10000012', '2016-02-06 22:07:42.0') 
,('10000028', '2016-02-04 13:18:48.0') 
,('10000028', '2016-02-04 13:30:42.0') 
,('10000028', '2016-02-04 13:30:55.0') 
,('10000028', '2016-02-05 16:48:41.0') 
,('10000028', '2016-02-05 16:58:34.0') 
,('10000028', '2016-02-07 15:44:33.0') 
,('10000028', '2016-02-07 16:29:00.0') 
,('10000039', '2016-02-03 21:16:49.0') 
,('10000039', '2016-02-03 21:17:50.0') 
,('10000039', '2016-02-03 21:18:49.0') 
,('10000039', '2016-02-03 21:19:49.0') 
,('10000039', '2016-02-03 21:20:50.0') 
,('10000039', '2016-02-03 21:21:50.0') 
,('10000039', '2016-02-03 21:22:51.0') 
,('10000039', '2016-02-03 21:23:53.0') 
,('10000039', '2016-02-03 21:24:49.0') 
,('10000039', '2016-02-03 21:25:50.0') 
,('10000039', '2016-02-03 21:26:50.0') 
,('10000039', '2016-02-03 21:27:49.0') 
,('10000039', '2016-02-05 21:58:59.0') 
,('10000039', '2016-02-05 21:59:58.0') 
,('10000039', '2016-02-05 22:00:58.0') 
,('10000039', '2016-02-05 22:01:58.0') 
,('10000039', '2016-02-05 22:02:59.0') 
,('10000039', '2016-02-05 22:03:58.0') 
,('10000039', '2016-02-05 22:05:00.0') 
,('10000039', '2016-02-05 22:05:58.0') 
,('10000039', '2016-02-05 22:06:58.0')
```

Really horrible query to get this working. With the restrictions you've mentioned and my lack of Amazon specific knowledge I've done the first two values for you below. If you did it this way you're going to end up with a massive statement but it will work. I'd heavily recommend researching further to see what equivalent functions you have available to you;

```
SELECT day1.udid
    ,MAX(day1.recday) day1
    ,MAX(day2.recday) day2
    ,DATEDIFF(day,MAX(day2.recday),MAX(day1.recday)) Day2Diff
    ,MAX(day3.recday) day3
    ,DATEDIFF(day,MAX(day3.recday),MAX(day1.recday)) Day3Diff
FROM #vvdays day1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT a.udid
        ,MAX(a.recday) recday
    FROM #vvdays a
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT udid
            ,MAX(recday) recday
        FROM #vvdays
        GROUP BY udid
        ) b ON a.udid = b.udid
    WHERE a.recday <> b.recday
    GROUP BY a.udid
    ) day2 ON day1.udid = day2.udid
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT a.udid
        ,MAX(a.recday) recday
    FROM #vvdays a
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT udid
            ,MAX(recday) recday
        FROM #vvdays
        GROUP BY udid
        ) b ON a.udid = b.udid
    LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT a.udid
        ,MAX(a.recday) recday
    FROM #vvdays a
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT udid
            ,MAX(recday) recday
        FROM #vvdays
        GROUP BY udid
        ) b ON a.udid = b.udid
    WHERE a.recday <> b.recday
    GROUP BY a.udid
    ) day2 ON a.udid = day2.udid
    WHERE a.recday NOT IN (b.recday, day2.recday)
    GROUP BY a.udid
    ) day3 ON day1.udid = day3.udid
GROUP BY day1.udid
```

The reason I have used MAX in for 'day1' is to return the first date. I have used it in 'day2' at the top level purely to turn it into an aggregate field, you'll only get one result here, it's a false aggregate that just lets the GROUP BY work correctly.

Comment: I try it , i got an output of - 1,2016-04-21 00:00:00.000,2016-04-19 00:00:00.000
2,2016-04-22 00:00:00.000,2016-04-19 00:00:00.000
 what this output means ?

Comment: what the meaning of "day1" and "day2"

Comment: In your original query, take a look at 'repeat_transaction1'. What this is doing is getting the equavilent of my day2 field using the lag function. It's then using a DATEDIFF between recday (which I have called day1) and the date gathered in the lag (that I've called day2). The only thing you need to do is the DATEDIFF function between the two dates but as the system you are using appears very specific I will let you decide the best way to do this.

Comment: but why you used max ?

Comment: I've updated my original reply that should help. You won't actually need the fields 'day1' and 'day2' in your final query, you'll be wanting 'DayDiff' but you'll have to work out how to do this in your version of SQL.

Comment: By the way, I've had a quick look at your previous questions on this site. While this is exactly what the site is for, if you're going to be asking questions it is considered polite to vote up responses to your questions.

Comment: great ! , i dont really understand the max part , sorry :(   , how it can replace the lag ? the lag is looking at the above date in each udid , the max gives me only the 2 higher dates in each udid , but about the rest ?

Comment: Ok, the first query gives you the first. The part in the left join gives you the MAX date that doesn't equal the first MAX that you calculated (e.g. give me the MAX date when you exclude the first MAX date, so you get the second MAX date)

Comment: You're going to have to embed each JOIN into the next one, and then add it into the NOT IN statement. I've just noticed that the query is producing data in the reverse order, you may have to change the instances of MAX to MIN depending on how your data is.

Comment: It's probably good practice if you take a look at what's been done and make sure you understand it. Break it down piece by piece and then you can create days 4-7 and understand what it's doing.

Comment: i tried , it will be very helpfull if you can show me just day 4 and i can continue by myself :)

Comment: Please learn what's going on above, I've provided you the first three steps, you need to carry on from here. There are a few reasons for this 1. You'll never learn if you don't try 2. We're here to help, not do it all for you 3. I've spent quite a lot of time on this query with, what appears, not a great deal of effort from yourself. I'm not meaning to be harsh at all, but you need that hunger for learning and to understand what's happening if you want to further yourself in this career path